# How do i store address in a register on x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a piece of code as below:

```
    .section .data
    myvar:
    .long 4,3,2,1

    .section .text
    .globl _start
    _start:
     movl $0, %edi
     movl myvar(,%ed1,4), %eax
     movl $0, %ebx
```

I would like to store address of last element of my array "myvar" in ebx (which is 1),  How do i do that ?

Answer (score 3):

My mental compiler outputs Intel syntax, not AT&T's, but you should get the idea:

```
lea eax, myvar + 12
```

eax now has the address of the '1' value.

Comment: thanks, need to check what's the equivalent of lea in AT&T syntax, i guess it's movl but not sure

Comment: lea is supported in at&t syntax as well - that I do know :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay i got it, we can use $myvar + N

example:

```
     .section .data 
      myvar: .long 4,3,2,1
     .section .text
     .globl _start
      _start:
     movl $0, %edi
     movl $myvar+0, %eax 
     movl $myvar+4, %ebx 
     movl $myvar+8, %ecx 
     movl $myvar+12, %edx 
     movl $myvar+16, %edi 
     movl $1, %ebx
     movl $1, %eax
     int $0x80
```